# Visual Studio Code not intellisensing withe typescript

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC on mac with script. At the start, it all went smoothly until yesterday. It does not intellisense anymore, not even basic JavaScript utils (e.g, `console.log`).

But it still kinda `intellisense` when I was editing `settings.json`, no where else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed definitions? Visual Studio Code relies on type definitions for IntelliSense. Basically you can install the TypeScript Definition utility (don't worry, it works for JavaScript too):

`npm install -g tsd`

Next you can query for definitions. For example, to find definitions for node you'd do:

`tsd query node`

To install the definitions, ensure you are in your project root directory then use the install action:

`tsd query node --action install`

You can do this for Express, Angular, or other types of libraries as well. After you perform those actions you should see IntelliSense working.